# using std::bind with std::reference_wrapper::get

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, functional-programming, stdbind

I'm trying to use `std::bind` to call `std::reference_wrapper::get` but I can't get it to compile. I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious but the compiler errors are not helping me out. This code is contrived and doesn't represent my actual use case:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void p() {std::cout << this << '\n';};
};

using ARef = std::reference_wrapper< A >;

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.p();
    auto p = std::bind (&A::p, std::placeholders::_1);
    p (a); // ok

    ARef ar (a);
    p (ar.get()); // ok
    auto get = std::bind (&ARef::get, std::placeholders::_1);
    p (get (ar)); // error
}
```

**Edit: This compiles fine with clang.**

**gcc 6.3.0 output:** http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00bffc7549193cb8

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:21:19: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind<std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>(std::_Placeholder<1>)>) (ARef&)'
         p (get (ar)); // error
                   ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:989:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>; _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:989:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:985:39: error: no match for call to '(std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>) (std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  = decltype( std::declval<_Functor&>()(
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
        _Mu<_Bound_args>()( std::declval<_Bound_args&>(),
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       std::declval<tuple<_Args...>&>() )... ) )>
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _MemFunPtr = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept; bool __is_mem_fn = true]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:985:39:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept, std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  -> decltype(std::__invoke(_M_pmf, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...))
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:985:39:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&(std::reference_wrapper<A>&))() const noexcept>'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1003:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>; _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1003:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:999:53: error: no match for call to '(const std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>) (std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  = decltype( std::declval<typename enable_if<(sizeof...(_Args) >= 0),
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
          typename add_const<_Functor>::type&>::type>()(
          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _MemFunPtr = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept; bool __is_mem_fn = true]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:999:53:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept, std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  -> decltype(std::__invoke(_M_pmf, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...))
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:999:53:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&(std::reference_wrapper<A>&))() const noexcept>'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1017:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>; _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1017:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1013:70: error: no match for call to '(volatile std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>) (std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  = decltype( std::declval<typename enable_if<(sizeof...(_Args) >= 0),
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
                        typename add_volatile<_Functor>::type&>::type>()(
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _MemFunPtr = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept; bool __is_mem_fn = true]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1013:70:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept, std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  -> decltype(std::__invoke(_M_pmf, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...))
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1013:70:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&(std::reference_wrapper<A>&))() const noexcept>'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1031:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>; _Bound_args = {std::_Placeholder<1>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1031:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1027:64: error: no match for call to '(const volatile std::_Mem_fn<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept>) (std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  = decltype( std::declval<typename enable_if<(sizeof...(_Args) >= 0),
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        typename add_cv<_Functor>::type&>::type>()(
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _MemFunPtr = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::*)() const noexcept; bool __is_mem_fn = true]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:600:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1027:64:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27: error: no matching function for call to '__invoke(A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept, std::reference_wrapper<A>&)'
  -> decltype(std::__invoke(_M_pmf, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...))
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
     __invoke(_Callable&& __fn, _Args&&... __args)
     ^~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional: In substitution of 'template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> typename std::result_of<_Callable&&(_Args&& ...)>::type std::__invoke(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&)() const noexcept; _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]':
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:603:27:   required by substitution of 'template<class ... _Args> decltype (std::__invoke(((const std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>*)this)->std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::_M_pmf, (forward<_Args>)(std::_Mem_fn_base::operator()::__args)...)) std::_Mem_fn_base<_MemFunPtr, __is_mem_fn>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {std::reference_wrapper<A>&}]'
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:1027:64:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/6.3.0/functional:245:5: error: no type named 'type' in 'class std::result_of<A& (std::reference_wrapper<A>::* const&(std::reference_wrapper<A>&))() const noexcept>'
```

Comment: To help people answer your question, you'll need to be more specific about the error.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the exact errors you get from your [mcve] (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Maybe the compiler errors aren't helping you out, but they might be able to help us out.

Comment: compiled fine, gcc 4.8, linux
0x7ffed79d12bf
0x7ffed79d12bf
0x7ffed79d12bf
0x7ffed79d12bf

Comment: I don't get an error with this code using MinGW either.

Comment: which you g++ command line arguments to compile?

Comment: @DenisZaikin here is is in coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00bffc7549193cb8

Comment: I'm going to be "that guy" (someone needs to be): why are you using `std::bind` instead of a lambda? Really, don't use `bind`.

Comment: looks like your code is fine, it gcc6.3 or  coliru.stacked-crooked.com issue.

Comment: seems a problem (or connected with) with stdlib; if you compile with `clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -stdlib=libc++ -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out` (so with libc++ instead of libstdc++), you program compile and run; but if you compile with `clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out` (so with stdlibc++) you have a similar error. I don't know hows right

Comment: @NirFriedman I would prefer to use a lambda and it would work but the code is more complex in my actual use case. I am defining a compare functor for a `std::priority_queue` that is a typedef in a class body. It is doable but more complex than `std::bind`.

Comment: @atb Suit yourself, but the equivalent code with a lambda compiles no problem. The advice to avoid `std::bind` completely comes from some very good sources: https://youtu.be/zt7ThwVfap0?t=27m45s. There's a lot of weird, bizarre, stuff in bind and most likely the interaction of that with reference wrapper, which is a bit unusual, is causing your problem.

Comment: @NirFriedman, as I said in the question "this code is contrived and doesn't represent my actual use case." I do agree that lambdas are easier to use in general but I believe this should compile as well. It seems like there may be a bug in gcc's stl.

Comment: @max66 you're right it seems to work with clang's stl, I guess this is a gnu stl bug then?

Comment: @atb - frankly, I don't know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is illegal to take the address of standard library member functions, because [implementations can add overloads and mutilate their signatures at will](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/member.functions). Therefore, the standard library, and in particular [the `INVOKE` protocol used by `bind` and friends](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/func.require#1), is designed around the assumption that it won't be passed a pointer to member of `std::reference_wrapper`. Invoking a pointer to member `pm` with a `reference_wrapper` `r` is equivalent to invoking `pm` with `r.get()`; i.e., the reference is unconditionally unwrapped.

See also [LWG issue 2219](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/lwg-issues/2219), which added `reference_wrapper` handling to `INVOKE`.

Comment: Does that mean that clang is wrong to compile this? Or is it just undefined behavior?

Comment: @atb It's undefined behavior.